# sparx EA confused on the version control status of a package

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have a package that is showing that a package (Deployables & Connectivity - PRD) is under version control, but has a red symbol:

[image]

If I try and delete the package, I get this error saying the package is checked out:

[image]

When I try to undo checkout, I get this error:

[image]

**Question:** how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess your model is in "offline" mode. Thats when the red symbol is shown. Check http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/9.2/projects_and_teams/offline_version_control.html

Comment: The rest of the model is not offline, it's only that one package and I can't find a way of getting it back online

Comment: If the Project-> Version Control -> Work Offline is unchecked, try to Resynchronize the Status of Version Controlled Packages, using Project Browser | right-click package | Package Control | Re-synch Status With VC Provider   or
Project Menu | Version Control | Re-synch Statuses of All Packages

Comment: Package re-sync returns the message _Package marked as 'Checked-Out Offline'.  Skipping this package._.  I've raised this as a bug with Sparx.

Comment: Ok, Just a quick thought, have you tried checking in that package?.

Comment: Yeah, EA throws the error: "You currently have no connection to Version Control, so you cannot check-in at this time."

Comment: Tried playing around with a few packages from different systems, (going offline / online, etc) but couldn't replicate this issue, guess SS support is the way to go as you've said

Comment: thanks for your help and your time looking into this!  Let's see what Spark support come back with...